# Using hreflang right

Tags: hreflang

When I checked my site with Google Webmaster Tools, I saw a warn about a missing `hreflang` tag.

I have a one-page website which is multi-language – German and English. When first visited the language will be the same as the browser language. If the user switches the language a cookie is set to store the selected language. But the language is **not** indicated in the URL (e.g. `/en` or `/de`), it’s just `mydomain.com` in both cases. What I do is changing the `lang` attribute in the `html` tag in `lang="de"` or `lang="en"`. I thought that would be friendly enough for Google.

My question is how to implement the `hreflang` correctly. All the example I find deal with different language folders like `mydomain.com/en/`, subdomains `en.mydomain.com` or extensions `mydomain.com/?lang=en`.

Should I switch the `hreflang` tag dynamically via JS depending on the selected language, so when the user sees the English version the `hreflang` would be `de-DE` because there’s the same content also in German:

```
<link rel="alternate" href="http://example.com" hreflang="de-DE" />
```

And when the user sees the Website in German:

```
<link rel="alternate" href="http://example.com" hreflang="en-EN" />
```

But that’s seems odd because the `href` value would be the same in both cases …

Answer (score 1):

You can only use Hreflang if you have 2 separate URLs. Then Google can send English users to the en page and the German users to the de page.